# Getting exception while converting date format

Tags: android, date, date-format

In my App,I have used Custom Calender View and Calender Adapter and I am getting date from Custom `CalendarView.java` in `yyyy-MM-dd` format through Intent and Its all working fine. But when I am trying to convert it in `dd-MM-yyyy` format, the app is getting crashed.

```
// Call Back method to get the Message form other Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // check if the request code is same as what is passed here it is
    // ACTIVITY_REQUESTCODE_CALANDER
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (null != data) {
            // fetch the message String
            String selectedDate = data.getStringExtra("SELECTEDDATE");

            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
            try {
                Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(selectedDate);
                SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "MM-dd-yyyy");
                // Or SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new
                // SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String finalString = newFormat.format(date);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, finalString,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Set the message string in textView
            editTextSelectDate.setText(selectedDate);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my LogCat,

```
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.calendardemo/com.example.calendardemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3209)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3252)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validateFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:268)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:316)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:369)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:253)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at com.example.calendardemo.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:52)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5368)
02-08 15:36:12.249: E/AndroidRuntime(4848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
```

Where am I wrong ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd);
```

instead of

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

in SimpleDateFormat **"Y"** is a Unknown pattern character. So don't use it and otherwise you will 
get ***IllegalArgumentException***.

Comment: And notice a second change, that "DD" was replaced by "dd" in this correct answer. Uppercase means "day-in-year" rather than "day-in-month".

Answer (score 1):

The trace says what's wrong:

```
Unknown pattern character 'Y'
```

To fix it change:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

To:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd);
```

Answer (score 0):

> there does not have captial y for year in java date format so use small y

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

replace by

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-DD");
```

Comment: Whoops, you missed the problem with "DD" also. See the [correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21644892/642706).